# Creating a Rankings (High Score) feature in my game in C++ //QT

Tags: c++, qt, save, game-development

Hey guys like many others on here I have just started off with programming. I am currently on a mission to make a card game. In this card game I the user plays against the computer. I am trying to add a rankings feature in my game. The top 5 users who beat the computer in shortest time will be displayed in a rankings table, and their positions should be replaced if someone beat their time. I have really struggled implementing this in my code;

- Must I use QTimer and store that time?
- How does one save this data on a file so that the data is still there when you run the game after exiting it
- Where do I start?

I would really appreciate any answers and or advice :}
01101000 01100001 01110110 01100101 00100000 01100001 00100000 01100111 01101111 01101111 01100100 00100000 01100100 01100001 01111001

Comment: You could do something like this :
 - when user beats computer, open a file, read the file and check if his time is in top 5 or not (algo should not be too difficult), format could be in **ms** for easy treatment (lower the better), then don't forget to **close** file
 - when you want to check ranking, open file take lines, close file, display rank for each line

Comment: I recommend starting with a *Hello World* program:  `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; return 0;}`  This program allows me to get the tools set up before adding more code.

Comment: You don't need to use `QTimer`, see the `std::chrono` library.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.